# Apply same event to multiple canvases but do different things per canvas - Jquery

Tags: jquery, events, canvas, mouseover

I basically have two canvases like so:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" class="canvases" ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" class="canvases" ></canvas>
```

And because they are running Processing.js and they can get heavy, I applied a mouseover and mouseout event to both buttons in jQuery like so:

```
num_canvases = 2;
canvasArray = [];

for (i = 0, i < num_canvases, i++) {
    canvasArray.push(Processing.getInstanceById('canvas'+i);
}

$('#canvas1').mouseover(function () {
    if (!force_play_all) {
        canvasArray[0].pause_or_resume(false);
    };
});
$('#canvas2').mouseover(function(){
    if (!force_play_all) {
        canvasArray[1].pause_or_resume(false);
    };
});
```

etc...

But now I'm expanding to 20 canvases and was looking for a way to apply the same mouseover event to each canvas and execute the pause_or_resume on whichever my mouse is over. I can't apply it per class or else they'll ALL go on or off. I'm thinking something like this but it still doesn't work. Ideas? :

```
$('.canvases').mouseover(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i <= numVars-1; i++) {
            var name_holder = '#canvas'+(i+1);
                $(name_holder).mouseover(function () {
                    canvas_instance = Processing.getInstanceById('canvas'+i);
                    if (pause_boolean) {
                        console.log(name_holder);
                        console.log(canvas_instance);
                        canvas_instance.pause_or_resume(pause_boolean);
                    };
                });
            };
        });
```

Comment: May I ask why you're using 20 canvasas as opposed to one split into 20 sections?

Comment: Also, why do you have nested `mouseover` events? It looks like you could just have the first `mouseover` and use `this.doSomething` format

Comment: If you're looking to pause the one that currently has `mouseover` it would be something like this: `$('.canvases').mouseover(function () { if (this.pause_or_resume()) { console.log(name_holder); console.log(canvas_instance); this.pause_or_resume(pause_boolean); };` I'm not sure how your `.pause_or_resume` function works though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah so I'm using 20 canvases cause processing redraws the entire instance 60 times per second so putting them all in one canvas will crash. As for the nested mouseover it was because I didn't know about using 'this' in these cases. The pause function takes a boolean; if it's true then it tells processing to stop drawing, if false, it tells it to resume the loop. I took your advice and solved it by doing the following.

Here's the way this got fixed just for future reference. Thanks Zeaklous!

```
$("[id^='canvas']").mouseover(function () {
    if (!force_play_all) {
        canvasArray[parseInt(this.id.replace('canvas',''))-1].pause_or_resume(false);
    };
});
```

Comment: Too bad I don't get rep for this, haha